# Generate all strings with length 100, only contains the letter $\begin{Bmatrix}A, B, C\end{Bmatrix}$ and satisfy some oher requirements

Tags: algorithms

Recently I am training for an algorithm contest. One of the older textbooks for that contest contains this question:

> Generate all strings $S$ that contained the letters $\begin{Bmatrix}A, B, C\end{Bmatrix}$  only, and satisfy these
> requirements:
>
> 1. The string's length (number of characters) must be exactly 100
> 2. No two adjacent strings are the same (formally this means that no two adjacent characters are the same and for all triplets $(a, b, c)$ such that $a \leq b < b + 1 \leq c \leq 100$, $S[a..b] \neq S[b+1..c]$ with $S[x..y]$ taken to be the substring from the $x$th letter to the $y$th letter
> 3. The letter 'B' must be used at few times at possible

I have an algorithm in mind, however it has time complexity of $O(3^n . n^3)$, which is too large for the requirement of $n = 100$. Do you have any suggestions or pieces of example code? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please credit the source where you encountered this question.  See our referencing rules: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing.  Thank you!

Comment: 1. What's the longest string you can make without using 'B', while following rules 1+2?  2. What's the longest string you can make, using only one 'B', while following rules 1+2?  3. What's the longest string you can make, using only two 'B's, while following rules 1+2?  4. Can you noticing any possible pattern?  Can you think of any way to check that pattern?

Comment: What are your thoughts?  What progress have you made?  We are not particularly looking for questions that consist solely of a contest-style task (and possibly a trivial exponential-time algorithm) and a request for us to show you the solution.  We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving contest-style tasks for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on.